# Converting my custom PHP framework in git submodule for every project

Tags: php, git, .htaccess, scope, git-submodules

I developed throughout the times my personal PHP Framework. It has some folders (in the root) and everything else is part of every web project.

I have more git projects. And, when I develop new features in framework folders, I have to manually update the frameworks of the others web projects.

**How can I have the framework in one single place (a git project on its own) and easily update every web project's framework?**

I've heard about submodules and subtrees. Submodules sound a good solution because I can develop new features in framework, when working to a specific web project. And after that I commit and push my submodule so all the others git web projects' frameworks can pull new commits.

Is it the best solution?

**My struggle:**

But submodules require having project in one subdirectory. For now, my framework has a `.htaccess` file in root which sends all requests to `web.php` (located also in root of web project). And `web.php` includes other necessary php files.

The good part is all php files has root as the scope (same scope as `web.php`).

How can I move all my framework files (including `.htaccess` and `web.php`) in a subdirectory (so could be easily treat as a submodule) and also having root scope for all my php files?

Comment: Sounds more like you need to distribute the project as a package which could be installed and updated into other projects using something like Composer

Comment: Make it as composer package. Make "install" script whom will copy htaccess and basic web.php to public folder in project. forget about submodules.

Comment: Hello. How do I make it as a composer package? I didn't do that before :(

Comment: I haven't done it myself but I'd be surprised if you can't find tutorials and documentation online already which explains the process